# Does Mathematics exists apart from the mathematician?

Tags: logic, philosophy

Does Mathematics exists apart from the mathematician? Explain yourself.
*Mathematics seems to be a projection of the mind. But from where the mind originates? Can the source of the mind be known or you have to be the source?*

Comment: Philosophy.se might give you better answers, but I would suggest that you show some evidence that you have researched the question yourself, and avoid using the imperative "Explain yourself".

Comment: related: http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unreasonable_Effectiveness_of_Mathematics_in_the_Natural_Sciences

Comment: *Explain yourself.* - Why? If mathematics exists apart from me, then certainly it can explain itself. ;-)

Comment: Everything is Mathematics. The laws of nature, the whole universe is mathematical. If you dont believe me, here is a quote by a famous physicist Paul Dirac: 

"God used beautiful mathematics in creating the world" - Paul Dirac. 


Now you don't think he told that without a reason right?

Comment: Mathematics seems to be a projection of the mind .But from where the mind originates?Can the source of the mind be known or you have to be the source?

Answer (score 6):

One could argue, does the mathematician even exist without mathematics?

Comment: Two upvotes, to cheer you up, and make you feel less depressed. ;-)